# Как я могу разбить строку в числа

Tags: python

Как я могу спарсить числа из url? На выходе в переменную я получаю ссылку допустим на паблик вк, она вида https://vk.com/public123456
Я попытался примером ниже, но я получаю [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] , а мне нужно 123456

```
list_num = []
for i in group:
    try:
        num = int(i)
        list_num.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(list_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Вам лучше использовать не `list`, а `str`, чтобы в итоге получилась нужного вида запись.
2. В таком случае, вам также не потребуется использовать `try except`, но можно и оставить, если вам необходимо.

```
string_num = ''
for i in group:
    try:
        string_num += str(i)
    except ValueError:
        continue
print(string_num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Лучше не пытаться специально генерить ошибки и их отлавливать. Вы можете получать тип символа и после сверять его с *int*. Но можете поступить еще лучше: в python есть много инструментов проверки строки на число. Ниже работающая функция, которая пробегается по все строке и запоминает все числа из нее

```
def get_link_num(link)    
    num_list = []
    for symb in link:
        if symb.is_digit():
            num_list.append(symb)
    return num_list
```